# Subset Leetcode, size of a List

Tags: subset

I am really curios about one thing when compiling, in the given code below, where I am creating nested for loop, I am giving as a limit

> subsetArr.size()

but when compiling it is saying memory exceeded, and if I define size just before the for loop

> int size = subsetArr.size()

and then passing limit as size

> i<size;

it is working fine. What can be the cause?

```
class Solution {
   public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
    
    List<List<Integer>> subsetArr = new ArrayList<>();
    subsetArr.add(new ArrayList());
    
    for(int num: nums){ 
        for(int i=0; i<subsetArr.size(); i++){
            List<Integer> takenList = new ArrayList<>(subsetArr.get(i));
            takenList.add(num);
            subsetArr.add(takenList);
        }
    }
    
    return subsetArr;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what this loop does:

```
for(int i=0; i<subsetArr.size(); i++){
    List<Integer> takenList = new ArrayList<>(subsetArr.get(i));
    takenList.add(num);
    subsetArr.add(takenList); // <-- here
}
```

Each iteration *adds* to the collection.  So in the next iteration, `subsetArr.size()` will be *larger*.  Thus you have a loop which indefinitely increases the size of the collection until it runs out of resources.

Contrast that to when you store the value:

```
int size = subsetArr.size();
```

In this case, while `subsetArr.size()` may change, `size` won't unless you update it.  So as long as you don't update `size` then you have a finite loop.

Comment: Thanks, I understood. But why it is not giving ConcurrentModificationException for ArrayList ?